# Hazelcast - How to completely remove the IQueue from the hazelcast during member at running mode

Tags: java, hazelcast

Currently I have queue added to the Hazelcast member on run time with following way.

```
QueueConfig queueConfig = new QueueConfig();
queueConfig.setName(task.getKey());
hazelcastInstance.getConfig().addQueueConfig(queueConfig);
```

Now after adding the queue, I am able to push the items to the queue from client and in my consumer application. I am able to consume all items.
I wanted to remove the entire `QueueConfig` (Considering the queue won't be available in any member) after my tasks are completed.

I tried with follwoing way, but this throws `UnsupportedExeption` from Hazelcast.
`hazelcastInstance.getConfig().getQueueConfigs().remove(key)`
Could anyone provide any hint or way to remove the `Iqueue` from the Hazelcast instance? I am really looking towards the solution and appreciate any help here.

Answer (score 1):

Hazelcast Client only supports overriding or adding new configurations on the client-side. You can take a look at source code here https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/master/hazelcast/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/client/impl/clientside/ClientDynamicClusterConfig.java#L501 , which operations doesn't support in client-side.

> To purge unused or empty queues after a period of time, use the `empty-queue-ttl` element. (programmatic way-> `queueConfig.setEmptyQueueTtl(TTL)`)

With above TTL config Hazelcast automatically purge empty queues after TTL expiration. I hope it helps.

Another solution is creating a new queue with your new configs if needed after your tasks in the queue are done.

Comment: Thanks @İlker Korkut for the response. I tried adding the ttl option  as queueConfig.setEmptyQueueTtl(1), but the purge is not happening. Just to confirm the value 1 is minute as unit or we need some constant to pass?  The second option is right which I am following, but the only consern is the empty queue will piled up for each set of tasks.

Comment: @user3876801 Do you have any declarative hazelcast.xml configuration. you can try to add empty-queue-ttl under your queue definition. By the way, this variable unit is seconds.